# Make Canvas/Grid with transparent area for underneath element

Tags: uwp-xaml

I am designing a tour view for my app, like below. In which, I place a canvas/grid, with a Ellipse element to focus underneath element of my page. The problem I am facing is, though I set the Opacity="0" for the ellipse, it does not get full transparency, I am able to understand the reason, but how to solve this issue.

```
<Grid x:Name="RootGrid">
<Stackpanel x:Name="AllElementsHere">
    <TextBox/>
    <TextBox/>
    <TextBox/>
    <TextBox/>
</<Stackpanel>

<Canvas x:Name="TourView" Background="Black" Opacity="0.5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Ellipse x:Name="TransparentArea" Fill="Red" Opacity="0" Canvas.Left="250" Canvas.Top="40" Height="200" Width="500"/>
</Canvas>
</Grid>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With my understanding, what you want actually is a spotlight effect, It's not a simple XAML layout question.

You could use [SpotLight Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.composition.spotlight) to create such effect and apply it on someone element on the XAML.

If you're not familiar with Composition APIs, you could check the [WindowsCompositionSamples](https://github.com/Microsoft/WindowsCompositionSamples). There's a **'Light -> Thumbnail Lighting'** sample page. It might be that you want.

[image]